# What is the best tool to show all of JDBC connections?

Tags: java, database, spring, transactions, database-connection

I'm working with Spring Boot application which use database (PostgreSQL). Is there some tool to detect all of connections to the database?

Comment: Which database are you using? like mysql, MSSQL, oracle or HSQL?

Comment: You could add Spring Boot Actuator dependencies, then you could check actuator metrics for information. This could help: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-actuator/

Comment: @DhiralKaniya I've updated my question